# RoR 3 : Devise, splitting edit user form to separate the change password, no method error for devise_error_message!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, devise

I'm trying to pull the change password fields into a separate form, but get an error with method devise_error_message!.

If I remove the method updating workings fine, however, if a validation fails it redirects to the registrations/edit.html.erb and gives the error messages. How would I get it to redirect back to the registrations/change_password.html.erb view and give the devise_error_messages! ?

All my code :
http://pastie.org/1907545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things that I think need to be resolved.

**1) Initialize the resource in the change_password action**

The call to `devise_error_messages!` fails because you aren't initializing the `resource` (your User model instance) in the `RegistrationsController#change_password` action. One way to do this is to make sure that the `authenticate_scope!` before filter, which is implemented in Devise::RegistrationsController, gets called on the `change_password` action. Try something like this in your RegistrationsController.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy, :change_password]

    def create
      ...
    end
end
```

If that doesn't work, you might want to simply call `authenticate_scope!` at the beginning of your `change_password` action.

**2) Redirect to change_password.html.erb in case of a failure**

Basically both of the `Devise::RegistrationsController#edit` action and your `RegistrationsController#change_password` action submit a form to the `Devise::RegistrationsController#update` action. What you want to do is make sure that when an update fails, if the form submission is coming from the `Devise::RegistrationsController#edit` action then you render the `registrations/edit.html.erb` view and similarly if the form submission is coming from the `RegistrationsController#change_password` action then you render `registrations/change_password.html.erb` view.

There are various ways to do this including relying on the flash hash to set a key in the `RegistrationsController#change_password` action (e.g. `flash[:change_password] = true`) and then check for the presence of this key if an error occurs during an update. Another approach would be to use a hidden field in your change_password form then similarly, if an error occurs during an update, check for the presence of this hidden field in the params hash. Something like this.

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name),
                       :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>  

  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :change_password, true %>
```

Either way you will need to override the Devise::RegistrationsController#udpate action. Something like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy, :change_password]

    def update
      if resource.update_with_password(params[resource_name])
        set_flash_message :notice, :updated if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
        respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
      else
        clean_up_passwords(resource)
        respond_with_navigational(resource) do
          if params[:change_password] # or flash[:change_password]
            render_with_scope :change_password
          else
            render_with_scope :edit
          end
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Give this a try but I think that should put you back on track.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! This seems really close. I'm getting no method error for respond_with_navigational, any idea this isn't inheriting? I even tried adding "include Devise::Controllers::Helpers" to the RegistrationsController but no luck

Comment: The `clean_up_passwords()` and `respond_with_navigational()` methods should be accessible directly in your customized RegistrationsController. There's no need to include any module. Do you have a stack trace or a complete error message?

Comment: Not sure what's going on. Try reverting lines 22 through 27 to `respond_with_navigational(resource) {render_with_scope :edit}` as it was before, just to see if the problem is caused by the block.

Comment: You're right its the method, the error is still there, no method error respond_with_navigational when the passwords don't match, and no method error is_navigational_format? when they do match. Why wouldn't the methods inherit?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would approach this by removing all customizations in your RegistrationsController and then work your way up by gradually adding customized code and see what causes these failures. I suspect it might have something to do with the `prepend_before_filter` so try commenting it out for now and see if things work again. If `prepend_before_filter` turns out to the culprit then try creating a `resource` directly in your `change_password` action (instead of using a before filter), i.e. add `build_resource` at the beginning of the `change_password` method.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the prepend filter, that is allowing me to call devise_error_messages!, I think I will have to sacrifice and have the change_password form work on success and on failure have it redirect back to the entire edit page.

Comment: Too bad. If the problem is isolated to `respond_with_navigational` then you may just want to call `render_with_scope` directly (basically get rid of lines 22 and 28). Good luck.

Comment: Did you eventually got this working? Im still want this feature but havent tried to implement it yet